# Using the camera from the Android device

Tags: android, permissions, camera

I would like to know if there is any way to use the front camera of the mobile without asking the persmission of the user while is using an application.

The logic would be:

- User triggers something
- The front camera starts recording
- Records during 5 seconds and saves the file

The user can't know the camera did this. Is it possible? I guess I will have to indicate in the manifest the camera is going to be used, but that is ok, what I don't want is that the user has to confirm the camera usage or anything while is using the app.

Thanks

Comment: Even if the law of your country allows this, aren't you afraid that you will violate American laws from your country and will be deported to US from some 3rd country?

Comment: It wouldn't be to spy anybody... and I know there are application that do this (the ones that help you if your mobile is stolen for instance)

Answer (score 0):

IMO this warning is a additional feature of google's android or the customized android versions from the manufacturers. I think it's a security feature, so you can't handle that behavior by your self.

This info is based on my opinion and talkings with front camera paranoid friends.

Comment: He could probalby catch the Broadcast event and cancel it. I'm almost sure it is possible but will require some reverse engineering.